# Автономная карта местности без тайл-сервера

Tags: openstreetmap, leafletjs, openlayers

Подскажите, пожалуйста, мне необходимо создать приложение, которое без интернета будет подгружать (автономную) карту какой-то местности и на ней можно будет точками указывать путь (точки будут привязаны к координатам широта и долгота).

Тайл-сервер поднимать **НЕ** предполагается, основной упор на автономию.

С сайтов скачаны файлы следующих форматов:

1. http://download.geofabrik.de/russia.html

- **russia-latest.osm.pbf** - который подходит для Osmium, Osmosis, imposm, osm2pgsql, mkgmap и других;
- **russia-latest.osm.bz2** - файл с расширением (yields OSM XML when decompressed; use for programs that cannot process the .pbf format).

2. https://data.maptiler.com/downloads/tileset/osm/russia/central-fed-district/

- **russia_central.mbtiles** - формат -> MBTiles (PBF)

Для создания web-интерфейса отображения картографических материалов на сайте планируется использовать библиотеку OpenLayers (или Leaflet если будет проще организовать задуманное) совместно с Webix.

При первичной настройке окружения и подключения указанных файлов все попытки завершились провалом.

Также, файл `russia_central.mbtiles` с помощью утилиты `mbutil` пытался разархивировать как в картинки так и в `PBF`, но как всю эту папку с файлами `.pbf` заставить обрабатываться OpenLayers не знаю, перепробовал множество примеров с https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/ но безрезультатно :(

Подскажите как прикрутить автономную кату к сайту или как можно это сделать из указанных файлов?!

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема. Брал mbtiles, с помощью программы QGIS резал нужный участок на png файлы. Там получалось автоматом раскидывал по нужным папкам и зумам. Брал leaflet и указывал путь к этой папке , у меня выходило таким образом:

```
    url={`${path.substring(
        0,
        path.length - 36
      )}./titles/satellite/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`}
```